# How do I split the Eth received from the minting of a ERC20 token

Tags: solidity, erc-20, ether, openzeppelin, address.transfer

I have an ERC20 token with a mint function that looks like this:

```
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT
pragma solidity ^0.8.0;

import "@openzeppelin/contracts/token/ERC20/ERC20.sol";

contract MyContract is ERC20 {

    constructor() public payable ERC20("MyContract", "MYCT") {}

    function mintOverride() public payable {
        address payable addressOne = payable(0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2); // Fake address
        address payable addressTwo = payable(0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db); // Fake address
        require(msg.value >= 0.05 ether, "Not enough ETH sent; check price!");   
        _mint(msg.sender, 1);
    }
}
```

But rather than have 100% precent of the Eth received going to a the contract issuer, I want to send some to addresses `addressOne` and `addressTwo` and potentially others

Answer (score 0):

You're over thinking it, either mint then distribute or mint directly to each wallet.

```
constructor(uint256 amount1, uint256 amount2, uint256 total) ERC20("MyContract", "MYCT") {
    address addressOne = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;
    address addressTwo = 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db;
    _mint(owner(), total - amount1 - amount2);
    _mint(addressOne, amount1);
    _mint(addressTwo, amount2);
}
```

Or

```
constructor(uint256 amount1, uint256 amount2, uint256 total) ERC20("MyContract", "MYCT") {
    address addressOne = 0xAb8483F64d9C6d1EcF9b849Ae677dD3315835cb2;
    address addressTwo = 0x4B20993Bc481177ec7E8f571ceCaE8A9e22C02db;
    _mint(address(this), total);
    this.transfer(addressOne, amount1);
    this.transfer(addressTwo, amount2);
    this.transfer(owner(), balanceOf(address(this))))
}
```